# Convert PDF content(with images) to the Inline HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Is there any Javascript library or code available to convert pdf content(with images) to the HTML inline content.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785198/use-pdf-js-to-statically-convert-a-pdf-to-html

Comment: Hi karthik, That post didn't contain any proper solution

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on the below API for this:

https://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/

or use the free online tool available for this.

https://www.pdftohtml.net/